# Instagram API - Can Influencers display Insights on my platform?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'm building all in one influencer marketing tool where one of the features is influencers can connect their social media accounts and list a service such as "Instagram Campaign for $50". When someone wants to book this service, they can see the influencer's audience insights. The booker uploads the campaign material, and the influencer can share their campaign directly from my platform to Instagram, and both the influencer and the booker can track the campaign performance via a booking brief. We don't sell influencer's audience insights, or make it available for a booker to download. We just allow an influencer to share the audience insights (if they want to) and allow a booker to view it. We charge a small commission per transaction.

I have read Instagram's latest policy a few times, however, I’m told by a business that wants to partner with us that Instagram does not allow you to track likes, views, etc, and that my company needs to use their partner platform instead, which only collects public profiles engagement from influencer profiles that have not opted in to their platform. Their business model works by charging a monthly retainer to access millions of influencer's engagement levels. To clarify his point, he referred to this clause below in the Instagram policy as to why our influencer's can't share their own insights with anyone.

29. "Don't transfer any data that you receive from us (including anonymous, aggregate, or derived data) to any ad network, data broker, influencer network, or other advertising or monetization-related service."
    https://www.instagram.com/about/legal/terms/api/

So my question is, if an influencer personally opts in to share their audience insights from Instagram to my platform, is my company breaching Instagram’s policy?

A very big thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid that this is a legal question and not a programming question.

Comment: Thanks Capricorn. I'm just hoping some developers can tell me if they've worked on apps similar and come across this..

Comment: I got you... However, I don't see a big difference whether your company is breaching Instagrams T&Cs or your clients do by sharing their audience insights with you. As long as one does, you unfortunately might have to rethink your business. The only helpful and reliable answer can probably be given by Instagram, so maybe it's worth asking their support.

Comment: Appreciate your comment. I'll contact Insta :)

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: @M.B Hey, any news ?